# PDF encryption in Php?

Tags: php, pdf, phpmailer

I need to send a pdf with Php in email, i cand send it, but I have the error of the image in PC,  but in smartPhone i dont have any problem with the pdf, can you help me please?

```
$nombre_archivo = "$nombreArchivo.pdf";
    $tipo_archivo = "application/pdf";
    $tamano_archivo = 10000;

    $MESSAGE_BODY  = "body";
    $email        = "angellaynezzacarias@gmail.com";

    $asunto     = "Detalle de compra";
    $mensaje    = utf8_decode($MESSAGE_BODY);
    $nombref    = "$nombreArchivo.pdf";

    $cabeceras     = "From: angellaynezzacarias@gmail.com\n";
    $cabeceras .= "Reply-To: angellaynezzacarias@gmail.com\n";
    $cabeceras .= "MIME-version: 1.0\n";
    $cabeceras .= "Content-type: multipart/mixed; ";
    $cabeceras .= "boundary=Message-Boundary"."\n";
    $cabeceras .= "Content-transfer-encoding: base64 "."\n";
    $cabeceras .= "X-attachments: ".$nombref;

    $body_top  = "--Message-Boundary"."\n";
    $body_top .= "Content-type: text/html; charset=US-ASCII"."\n";
    $body_top .= "Content-transfer-encoding: base64 "."\n";
    $body_top .= "Content-description: Mail message body"."\n";

    $cuerpo = $body_top.$mensaje;

    if($tamano_archivo>0)
    {
    //Leo el fichero
       $oFichero = fopen("pdf//$nombreArchivo.pdf", 'r');
       $sContenido = fread($oFichero, filesize("pdf//$nombreArchivo.pdf"));
       $sAdjuntos = chunk_split(base64_encode($sContenido));
       fclose($oFichero);
       //Adjunto el fichero
       $cuerpo .= "\n\n"."--Message-Boundary"."\n";
       $cuerpo .= "Content-type: Binary; name=".$nombref."\n";
       $cuerpo .= "Content-transfer-encoding: base64"."\n";
       $cuerpo .= "Content-disposition: attachment; filename=".$nombref."\n";
       $cuerpo .= $sAdjuntos."\n";
       $cuerpo .= "--Message-Boundary--";
    }
    //Envío el correo
    mail($email, $asunto, $cuerpo, $cabeceras);
```

[image: <code>[![enter image description here][1]][1]</code>]

Comment: Can someone translate the error message?

Comment: you used the PDFBox label. How is this related to PDFBox?

Comment: I suggest you compare the original PDF file and the PDF file received by mail to see whether they are different. If you don't know how to compare files, please upload both to a sharehoster and post the links here.

Comment: Acrobat cannot open the file attachment because your PDF file attachment settings do not allow this file type to be opened.

Comment: Rather than reinventing the wheel, I'd recommend trying to use a library that will do this correctly with much less code, like PHPMailer that you tagged the question with.

Comment: I didt, but doesnt  work, in smartPhone I can see the pdf, but in PC Icant, i generate pdf file with Php.

Comment: Your file has only 127 bytes in the image from your question. While it is possible that a PDF is that small, it is unlikely.

Comment: Why did you use the word "encryption" in your question? The question as nothing to do with encryption. A better title would be e.g. "mail PDF file attachment with php". I mention this because better titles results in your question being seen by the right people. Have also a search "php mail pdf attachment" and see whether one of these answers help.

Comment: I use "encryption"  because I generate the pdf with Php.  That pdf